# Add custom command to own VS Code extention in "view/title"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to add my own command in a Visual Studio Code extension in the upper "view/title" row. For example, like the built-in "Extension"-View:
[image: example]

I couldn't figure out from the [menu-contributions API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) how this works. I specified a custom `ViewContainer` in the package.json, which in turn contains multiple views:

```
{
  "viewsContainers": {
    "activitybar": [
      {
        "id": "my-view",
        "title": "My View",
        "icon": "media/logo.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  "views": {
    "my-view": [
      {
        "id": "profiles",
        "name": "Profiles"
      },
      {
        "id": "templates",
        "name": "Templates"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Since I have a command that goes across all views, I would like to have the button at the height of the ViewsContainer (as in the image). Is that possible?

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at the official [TreeView Extension Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample). Inside the `package.json` of that sample, you'll find a view with the ID `nodeDependencies`. It has a "refresh" command displayed the way you intend to.

Comment: Hi @ct_jdr, thanks for your comment. I saw this example repository before. This sample only works as I want because the view container `packageExplorer` has only one view, `nodeDependencies`. If I add another view to the view container, (as shown in my example code) the `refresh` button moves one hierarchy level down.